# Error in Keras - 'int' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, generator, tf.keras

I'm using VGGFace model. I am using tensorflow.keras with Tensorflow version 2.4.1. The following is the function for generator:

```
def gen(list_tuples, person_to_images_map, batch_size=16):
    ppl = list(person_to_images_map.keys())
    while True:
        batch_tuples = sample(list_tuples, batch_size // 2)
        labels = [1] * len(batch_tuples)
        while len(batch_tuples) < batch_size:
            p1 = choice(ppl)
            p2 = choice(ppl)

            if p1 != p2 and (p1, p2) not in list_tuples and (p2, p1) not in list_tuples:
                batch_tuples.append((p1, p2))
                labels.append(0)

        for x in batch_tuples:
            if not len(person_to_images_map[x[0]]):
                print(x[0])

        X1 = [choice(person_to_images_map[x[0]]) for x in batch_tuples]
        X1 = np.array([read_img(x) for x in X1])

        X2 = [choice(person_to_images_map[x[1]]) for x in batch_tuples]
        X2 = np.array([read_img(x) for x in X2])

        yield [X1, X2], labels

valx=gen(val, val_person_to_images_map, batch_size=100)

for i in valx:
    valx=i
    break
```

During execution of model it gives error: 'int' object has no attribute 'shape':

```
history = model.fit_generator(gen(train, train_person_to_images_map, batch_size=16), use_multiprocessing=True,
                    validation_data=(valx[0],valx[1]), epochs=50, verbose=1,
                    workers = 4, callbacks=callbacks_list, steps_per_epoch=200)
```

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-114-1c7e5a32eed2> in <module>()
      1 history = model.fit_generator(gen(train, train_person_to_images_map, batch_size=16), use_multiprocessing=True,
      2                     validation_data=(valx[0],valx[1]), epochs=50, verbose=1,
----> 3                     workers = 4, callbacks=callbacks_list, steps_per_epoch=200)

7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in _get_dynamic_shape(t)
    805 
    806     def _get_dynamic_shape(t):
--> 807       shape = t.shape
    808       # Unknown number of dimensions, `as_list` cannot be called.
    809       if shape.rank is None:

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

I looked up similar queries, but I don't seem to understand which line is causing the error.
I have tried changing code in gen function to

```
for x in batch_tuples:
    x=np.array(x)
    if not len(person_to_images_map[x[0]]):
         print(x[0])
```

But that gives me another error :

```
'generator' object is not subscriptable in python
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check image resize in `person_to_images_map[x[0]]`